# Python Sort Collections.DefaultDict in Descending order

Tags: python

I have this bit of code:

```
    visits = defaultdict(int)
    for t in tweetsSQL:
         visits[t.user.from_user] += 1
```

I looked at some examples online that used the sorted method like so:

`sorted(visits.iteritems, key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)`

but it is giving me:

`"TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable"`

I am not sure why.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

iteritems is a method. You need parenthesis to call it: `visits.iteritems()`.

As it stands now, you are passing the iteritems method itself to `sorted` which is why it is complaining that it can't iterate over a function or method.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I think one of these forms is a little more succinct as the first argument only needs to be an iterable not an iterator.

```
sorted_keys = sorted(visits.keys(), reverse=True)
sorted_keys = visits.keys().sort(reverse=True)
```

Comment: He wants to sort on value, not on key